# Meteor Collection find()/fetch() working sometimes

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I started working with meteor which seems to be good for my use, a problem occurred where I get my documents only 9/10 times. I think I implemented something wrong.

I use Angular 1.5 and Typescript

My collection gets created in the lib folder at /

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Locations= new Mongo.Collection('locations');
```

then the collection gets imported to my service

```
import {app} from '../../js/lib/app';
import {Locations} from '../../../lib/collections';

export class LocationsService {

    locations: any;

    constructor(){
        console.log('Constructor called');
        this.locations = Locations
                .find({})
                .fetch();
        console.log('documents loaded');
        console.log(this.locations);
    }

    public createLocation(any:any){
        Locations.insert(any);
    }

    public updateLocation(identity:any, modifier:any){
        Locations.update(identity,modifier);
    }

}

app.service('locationsService', LocationsService);
```

Here are the console.logs from 3 different page refreshes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It looks like the amount of docs I get is totally random.

Comment: It's not random. You need to wait for the collection to be ready, which you can do in the route (if you are using ui router)

Comment: could you post more information about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My new Service simply subscribes

```
export class LocationsService {

    locations:any;

    constructor(){
        console.log('Constructor called');
        //Subscribe to a collection//localStorage.getItem('ID')
        Meteor.subscribe('locations', 2223 );
        this.locations = Locations;
        console.log('documents loaded');
    }

    public createLocation(any:any){
        Locations.insert(any);
    }

    public updateLocation(identity:any, modifier:any){
        Locations.update(identity,modifier);
    }

}

app.service('locationsService', LocationsService);
```

In my controller i simply add the fetching of my documents in the Tracker.

```
import {app} from '../../js/lib/app';
import {LocationsService} from './LocationsService';
import {Tracker} from 'meteor/tracker';

export class LocationsController {

    static $inject = ['locationsService','$reactive','$scope'];

    public $reactive: any;
    public $scope: any;

    public locations: any[];


    constructor(private locationsService: LocationsService, $reactive:any, $scope:any){
        this.locationsService = locationsService;
        this.$reactive = $reactive;
        this.$scope    = $scope;
        $reactive(this).attach(this.$scope);
        Tracker.autorun(() => {
            //console.log('autorun');
            this.locations = locationsService.locations.find({}).fetch();
            console.log(this.locations)
        });
    }

    public createLocation(location:any){
        console.log('Locations does what it should');
        console.log(location);
        this.locationsService.createLocation(location);
    }

    public updateLocation(location:any, modifier:any){
        this.locationsService.updateLocation(location._id,modifier)
    }

}

app.controller('locationsController', LocationsController);
```

The only problem I have now is that the modell updates like a charm but not the view when I create new locations. The autorun works and the new location gets saved in my collection but I see it only if I reload. But that one is low priority for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that will help you. It uses the "resolve" feature of ui-router to hold up loading of the page until data is loaded. In this case there are two things being resolved:

1. User record
2. Elders record

The second one needs an "elderid" from users.profile in order to find an elder record.

```
function config($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
      'ngInject';
      $stateProvider
        .state('member.calendar', {
          url: '/calendar',
          template: "<membercalendar></membercalendar>",
          resolve: {
            currentUser: ($q) => {
              var deferred = $q.defer();

              Meteor.autorun(function () {
                if (!Meteor.loggingIn()) {
                  if (Meteor.user() == null) {
                    deferred.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED');
                  } else {
                      deferred.resolve(Meteor.user());
                  }
                }
              });

              return deferred.promise;
            },
            elder: ($q) => {
              var deferred = $q.defer();

              Meteor.autorun(function () {
                if (!Meteor.loggingIn()) {
                  if (Meteor.user() == null) {
                      deferred.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED');
                  } else {
                    deferred.resolve(Elders.find({_id: Meteor.user().profile.elderid}));
                  }
                }
              });

              return deferred.promise;
            }
          }
        });

    }
```

This works well if you want the data to be loaded fully before the page loads. If you don't mind an asynchronous update to the page, you can use getReactively to make a helper run once the data has resolved. I can give you example code for that too if you like.

Comment: Sorry for the long reaction but i would like to know the getReactivly example

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if you feel that it has solved your problem, which it should have done. The reason for doing that is so that It can be a reference for other people who may have a similar problem to know that it worked for you. The getReactively part could either be an extension to this or another question, which I can answer when you have marked this as correct

Comment: I used Tracker.autorun() in my controller instead in my routing I'll post my new code asap